# How to lpad a variable with space in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can someone help me with this requirement

```
DECLARE @str  VARCHAR(10) 
Set @str='M10'
```

I have this string how do i lpad this with spaces something like this

```
@sstr='       M10'
```

Basically the size is 10 so 7 spaces and then the string value M10

I am using SQL2005

Regards

Comment: Hi Andriy
I think that will work but how do I assign the value of that statement to a variable. Also I am not fetching any value from any tables .Its just a variable value which I want to lpad. Sorry I am a novice in T-SQL

Comment: There's no built-in padding function in Transact-SQL, you need to combine other string functions to get the desired result – that's what the answer in the linked question is about. Don't mind the SELECT statement, look at the expression the SELECT statement is using. Being a novice you probably just need to get acquainted with [T-SQL string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx). That may help you to understand the solution better as well as to learn how to solve other string processing problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks Andriy for the guidance I will go through them

Answer (score 0):

`Space()` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950.aspx

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10) 
    SET @str = 'M10'

SET @str = Space(7) + @str

--Optional, trims it to 10 characters
SET @str = Right(Space(10) + @str, 10)
```

Alternative function: `Replicate()` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx

```
SET @str = Right(Replicate(' ', 10) + @str, 10)
```

Comment: Hi
THIS WILL HARDCODE THE SPACES TO 7 . i WANT IT TO BE DYNAMIC THE sTRING VALUE CAN CHANGE FROM M10 to 10 then we need 8 spaces. Basicallyy need to lpad  space to that string

Comment: @user3313579 See the last line of code: this will make the whole thing 10 spaces regardless of how long `@str` is. It does this by adding 10 spaces to the beginning and then trimming the string to the rightmost 10 characters.

Comment: Thanks bro it works. I have another question and sorry for being a pain . My stored procedure will have a  2 inputs one  a string and other one will be a array of integers . I need to read this input string and the second parameter which is a array of integer values and then insert in to table and then also out a list of values in to a array . Can you please help

Comment: @user3313579  SQL doesn't have arrays. If you're trying to pass in a list of comma separate numbers, search around, that question has been answered here a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i get credit for originality. The other solution has been posted so often for the same question.

```
set @str = reverse(cast(reverse(@str) as char(10)))
```

Comment: nice trick you are forcing spaces by converting it to `CHAR(10) and than reversing that to get spaces on left side.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use use `SUBSTRING()` and `LEN`

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10) = 'M10'
   ,@padding VARCHAR(10) = '                      '

SET @str =  SUBSTRING(@padding, 0, 11 - LEN(@str)) + @str

SELECT @str,LEN(@str)
```

Now taking code from @Gvee and changing it to my first example

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10) = 'M10'

SET @str = Space(10-LEN(@str)) + @str

SELECT @str
```